.net 8 Blazor Antiforgery attacks for internal API
I created a Blazor .NET 8 project with auto. rendering and individual account authentication from Blazor WebApp template.
On the server side, I added an internal API with an [Authorize] attribute on the class and a POST method.
On the client side, I have a Razor page with a service that makes a POST request to the internal API using HttpClient.
I want to make sure that in my case, my API is protected against Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) attacks. Does a Blazor project with individual account authentication automatically protect an internal API, or do I need to do something to secure it?
Project options
Server side / TestController.cs
namespace WebAppAutoIndividual.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/test2")]
    [Authorize]
    public class Test2Controller : Controller
    {

        private readonly ITest2Service _service;

        public Test2Controller(ITest2Service service)
        {
            _service = service ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(service));
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public DataTest[] Read()
        {
            var items = _service.Get().Result;

            return items;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public void Create([FromBody] DataTest dto)
        {
            _service.Add(dto);
        }

    }
}

Client side / page.razor
@page "/form-auto-controller"
@attribute [Authorize]
@rendermode InteractiveAuto

@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
@using System.Net.Http
@using WebAppAutoIndividual.Client.Services

@inject ILogger<FormAutoController> Logger
@inject ITest2Service Service

<PageTitle>Formulaire avec Controleur avec rendu auto</PageTitle>

<p>Mode de rendu : @(OperatingSystem.IsBrowser() ? "Wasm" : "Server")</p>

<EditForm Model="Model" OnValidSubmit="SubmitAsync" FormName="StarshipClientAutoRender">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />
    <label>
        Prénom :
        <InputText @bind-Value="Model!.FirstName" />
    </label>
    <label>
        Nom :
        <InputText @bind-Value="Model!.Name" />
    </label>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</EditForm>

@if (allModels == null)
{
    <p>Loading ...</p>
}
else
{
    <label> je suis @serviceName</label>
    <button @onclick="Refresh">Refresh</button>

    @foreach(DataTest i in allModels)
    {
        <p>@i.Name, @i.FirstName</p>
    }

}

@code {
    [SupplyParameterFromForm]
    public DataTest? Model { get; set; }
    private DataTest[] allModels { get; set; } = null;
    private DateTime DateTimeRefresh = DateTime.Now;
    private string serviceName = "aucun";

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        Model ??= new();
        serviceName = Service.Whois();
        allModels = await Service.Get();
    }

    protected async Task Refresh()
    {
        allModels = await Service.Get();
        DateTimeRefresh = DateTime.Now;
    }

    private async Task SubmitAsync()
    {
        Logger.LogInformation("Prénom Nom = {fisrtname} {name}", Model?.FirstName, Model?.Name);

        if (Model != null)
        {
            await Service.Add(Model);
        }
    }

}

Client side / Service Http
namespace WebAppAutoIndividual.Client.Services;

public class Test2ProxyService : ITest2Service
{
    private readonly HttpClient _http;
    public Test2ProxyService(HttpClient http) { 
        _http = http;
    }

    public string Whois() { return nameof(Test2ProxyService); }

    public async Task Add(DataTest test)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Service 2 POST depuis le client");
        await _http.PostAsJsonAsync("/api/test2", test);
    }

    public async Task<DataTest[]> Get()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Service 2 GET test depuis le client");
        var result = await _http.GetFromJsonAsync<DataTest[]>("/api/test2");
        return result;
    }
}


From my research , there is some code needed for your http request . https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-web-api?view=aspnetcore-8.0#antiforgery-support Also there are discussions that recommended that JWT token could be a better choice to prevent CSRF.

I agree, a solution with JWT token might be a better choice to prevent CSRF. I imagine that's not possible with asp.net basic authentication and it is necessary to go through an Azure B2C type solution, right?

I think it is unnecessary to use Azure B2C unless you have other complex authentication needs.
